# Included External Js in Yii

Tags: php, yii

My customer bought a project prepared with Yii.
I met with Yii and Everything is perfect.
I have a small problem and I didn't find any solutions yet.
I have seo tracking script with core php.
I must add my code in view/main.php

```
<script id="domain" data-name="6208315" type="text/javascript" src="https://domain/seo/js/analytics_js/client.js"></script>
```

But I didn't find any solutions, how can i add this code for my main.php.
Generally 
Usually added this code in footer.php for core php projects.

I hope you can help me about this problem. Thank you.

Comment: you can add it before body tag ends.

Comment: Thank you for solution. But I tried this. It's doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Open file with -Assets suffix in assets/ folder (usually AppAsset.php) and add your js file in $js var:

```
public $js = [
     // ...
     'https://domain/seo/js/analytics_js/client.js',
];
```

Comment: Thank you for solution. But this doesn't work for me. I must add id="domain" data-name="6208315" values for external script.